# Android kotlin fragment: how to get the activity's viewmodel

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewmodel

In a `Fragment`: how do you get a reference to the `ViewModel` of the `Activity`?

The Android docs say to do

```
  private val model: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

but -- as is normal for Android docs -- it doesn't work.

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option

Others suggest

```
model = ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

but that isn't allowed because `ViewModelProviders` is deprecated.

So: how do you do it?
Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

it seems like jvm version problem,try add this in your build.gradle

```
 compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
```